# Can I build Chocolatey packages on Linux?

Tags: chocolatey

It's pretty easy to build Chocolatey packages on a Windows machine. But, so far, I haven't found a documented way to build packages on Linux.

For example, how would I run `choco.exe`, a Windows executable, on Linux?

Comment: If `choco.exe` is a .NET assembly, you should be able to run `mono choco.exe` to run it on Linux. The issue is that I can't figure out how to obtain the executable without actually installing Chocolatey (and the install script doesn't seem to work on Linux)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since around 2014, running Chocolatey on Linux machines (using Mono have been supported). Rob Reynolds, the creator of Chocolatey actually demoed this capability at [PuppetConf 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZl_wKSciVk). The demo of creating a package starts around the 11 minute mark in that video. As a result, the process of building a Chocolatey package, i.e. `choco pack` is currently supported today.

**NOTE:** I have assumed that the terminology of building a package is the same as creating a package.

Currently, a choco binary, which is compiled for usage on Linux is not distributed anywhere. However, we do currently build Choco using Travis. You can see the YAML file [here](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/master/.travis.yml). In theory, you should be able to grab the source code from GitHub, then execute the same commands that Travis does, to generate a compiled version of choco that you can use on Linux.

Comment: Do you know if Rob publishes the mono executable or do you have to build from source or something?

Comment: It is not published, but we run Travis-CI against it, so it shows how it is built and tested.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how I can run choco pack on Linux (Ubuntu)? Can I use mono from the Ubuntu repository (currently version 4.2.1.102)? How can I use it if it's not published according to @ferventcoder?

Comment: @pascal-mages I have updated the answer with some notes that will point you in the right direction.  This isn't something that I have ever done though.

Comment: If `choco.exe` is a .NET assembly, you should be able to run `mono choco.exe` to run it on Linux, without actually having to recompile it (since .NET assemblies use bytecode).